# OAuth2.0 works from Postman UI (authorization helper), doesn’t work via manual request

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, postman, authorization, identityserver4

The issue I’m facing is I’m trying to manually get the token from the API for the sake of automation. What I did is I configured IdentitySever to grant token on user credentials it worked fine when request has been sent via OAuth UI:
[image]

I’m getting the following request/response (viewed in console):
[image]

Now the issue is that I’m sending the exact same request but manually, but it fails:
[image]

I'm getting 'invalid_client' error instead of Token
I'm not overriding IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator so I'm using default implementation.
Anything else that I’m missing? Does UI do something else under the hood? Did I miss something?

The requests are identical, I copied over clients, passwords etc in case anything is different.
I’ve also tried to do the token request via get+query string, but same result

I tried changing the clientid, clientsecret, but no luck so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your manual request. It should be 'client_secret' but not 'cliend_secret'.

OAuth2 doesn't understand this field and as a result of this, it assumes that you didn't pass the secret of the client in the request and thus it throws an 'invalid_client' error.

[image]